# Master Page Placeholder Text Frame that can be changed on the pages

Tags: adobe-indesign

What is the best way to create a placeholder text frame on the master page?

I have several pages that are basically section title pages, so everything on the page will be the same in terms of formatting, position, etc. Except for the obvious title of the section. Or should I just create a new text frame on each section page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a text frame in your Master Page and then style/format it the way you wish it to be across all pages.  As you can see below, I've formatted mine the way I wish my titles to appear on all pages:

[image]

To edit Master Page items, on an page-by-page basis, simply <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+Click on the items you wish to edit:

[image]